# Graphic sequence and connectivity

Tags: graph-theory

The question is as follows:

> Given the graphic sequence d=$\langle d_1,d_2,...,d_n\rangle$. Assuming $d_i\ge2$ for every i. Show that a simple and connected graph with such graphic sequence exists.

The proposoal given on how to approach it is to assume that the number of components is the minimal number. I also assume I will have to use 2-switch'es and Berge's theorem.

I am unsure what they mean, though, with number of components being the minimal number. I thought about assuming there exists a simple with such graphic sequence (granted) that has two components (not granted at all). I could then go about proving with 2-switch that I can connect the two components. However I am not sure how it proves that a simple and connected graph exists for such a graphic sequence, as the latter part is not easily taken for granted. Beyond that I am unsure on how to approach it, at all.

I will extremely appreciate any hints on how to try to prove/show what is needed!

Edit: I also considered trying to go on with induction (for the number of components), but that obviously failed.

Edit II: following Jamisans comment, I can add and state that n$\ge$3, since otherwise for $d_i=2$ and certainly for larger $d_i$'s there is no simple graph that realizes the graphic sequence, thus contradicting the fact that it is a graphic sequence.

Comment: Are there any other restrictions on $n$ or the $d_i$ besides the lower bound that you gave? For instance, the sequence $d=2,2$ is not realizable by any simple connected graph but meets the given bound.

Comment: Note that they said that the given sequence is a graphic sequence, so it upholds that there is some simple graph that ralizes it. d=2,2 is not realizeable by any simple graph what so ever, so it does not meet the fact that d is a graphic sequence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since we're told the sequence is graphic, there exists at least one simple graph that realizes it. Suppose that none of the graphs that realize the sequence are connected. Then out of all such graphs there is one with the fewest number of connected components, call it $G$. Let $G$ have $k$ connected components. Let $xy$ be an adjacent pair in one component of $G$, and let $wz$ be an adjacent pair in a different component. By Berge's theorem we can perform a 2-switch on those four vertices without altering the degree sequence. Since all of the vertices have degree at least two, the two components are now joined, and the number of connected components of the new graph is $k-1$. This gives us a contradiction since we assumed $G$ had the fewest connected components of all simple graphs that realize the sequence.

Comment: Amazing. Didn't think of contradiction. Thank you!

Comment: What if both edges are  cut edges?

Comment: Good point. You'd have to argue that there exist at least one non-cut edge in each component (coming from a cycle), which it seems like you could do based on the degree lower bound.

Comment: You can easily do it by choosing say x and w to be the end-point vertex of the maximal path in each component, and y and z respectively being their neighbouring vertexes on the path itself. Then it's easily proveable xy and wz are not cut-vertexes, and thus the 2-switch connects the components.