# How to prove that if p $\le$ q+1 , then G is connected.

Tags: graph-theory

prove if p $\le$ q+1 , G is connected.

p is the number of vertices, q is the number of edges.

I would like to start with p=q+1. I remember that there is a theorem states "If G is connected, and p=q+1, then G is a tree." but I cannot use it because there is an assumption of G is connected.

So I do not know how to start.

Here is the original question:[image]

I simplify it to : 
2q $\ge$ 2(p-1)

q $\ge$ p-1

p $\le$ q+1

Comment: This isn't true - consider two copies of $K_4$ (the complete graph on four vertices). It has 12 edges and 8 vertices. Do you have any extra assumptions? Is $G$ acyclic?

Comment: You need to assume that G has no isolated vertices, otherwise the claim is false. The theorem you state actually works with the same hypothesis: "If G has no isolated vertices and $p=q+1 then G is a tree$".

Comment: @Dap I added the original question, could you take a look again? Thank you a lot!

Comment: @RedundantAunt  I added the original question, could you take a look again? Thank you a lot!

Comment: jamisans answer here works for $d_i\geq 2$: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/694212/graphic-sequence-and-connectivity/694265

Comment: The first question and the second one (edited question) are not same. Because in the second one you give more information about degrees ($d_{i}\geq 1$).

Comment: @HasanHeydari: it's more of a logical difference - the difference between "show every $G$ is connected" and "show there exists a connected $G$"

Comment: @Dap Thank you for the link but I didn't learn about the Berge's theorem yet. Is there any other ways to do the proof?

Answer (score 2):

Your first claim is wrong and this is a counter example.

[image]

Your second claim (edited version) is also wrong and this is a counter example.

[image]

Comment: I added the original question, could you take a look again? Thank you a lot!

Comment: Yes there will be some counter example but the edited version question means we just need to prove there exist one connected graph.

Answer (score 1):

Let $G$ be the disjoint union of two copies of the complete graph $K_n$. Then $G$ has $p=2n$ vertices and $q=n^2+n\gg p$ edges while not being connected.

Comment: I added the original question, could you take a look again? Thank you a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Consider a graph $G$ that is disconnected and has a cycle. I claim we can produce another graph $G'$ with the same degree sequence as $G$ but with fewer connected components. Iterating, we end up with a graph with the same degree sequence that is either connected or acyclic. But an acylic graph satisfies $p=q-k$ where $k$ is the number of components; if $k>1$ this would contradict the assumption $p\geq q-1$.

To prove the claim, consider an edge $uv$ in a cycle, and any edge $xy$ in a different connected component. Construct $G'$ from $G$ by a "switch": deleting the edges $uv,xy$ and adding edges $ux,vy$. This doesn't change the degree sequence. Since $uv$ was in a cycle in $G$, $u$ is still in the same connected component as $v$ in $G'$, which implies that $u,x,v,y$ are all in the same connected component in $G'$. So any vertices that were connected before are still connected, and since $u$ and $x$ are now in the same component, the number of connected components has decreased by one as required.

---

Another argument is to inspect the construction in the proof of Erdős–Gallai as in the [Havel–Hakimi algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Havel%E2%80%93Hakimi_algorithm), but that relies on knowing a particular proof.